# GIMP 2.8.22 How to SELECT ALL text objects in all layers and change font size of all at once?

Tags: gimp, text, layers, font-size

(GIMP 2.8.22)

I have several text objects labeling parts of the human body and I want to increase the font size of all of them to 20 pts. Each text object was automatically put into its own layer, and I want to leave it like that, if possible. How do I **SELECT ALL** of the individual text objects in the entire drawing (**all layers**) and change them all at once?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AFAIk you can't, you would would need a script that runs on all layers... But in Gimp 2.8 you can have several fonts/sizes in a text layer and you could have to reposition/resize the layers, so this would not be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin [here](https://github.com/pixlsus/registry.gimp.org_static/blob/master/registry.gimp.org/files/group_chfont.py.txt) - save it as a .py file in your GIMP plugins folder, and restart GIMP.

Put all your text layers in a layer group, and select the layer group in the layers palette.

Click *Group > Change font*

[image]

Comment: Where do I get 'Group > Change Font' option?

Comment: @digitguy - this is a very old answer, not sure if this script will still work in the latest version of GIMP, but it was located under Image > Group > Change Font

Comment: Hmm.. I do not see 'Group' under Images, so may be the script isn't working :(. Is there any other way now in newer Gimp version?

Comment: @digitguy - yeah sounds like it's not working. AFAIK, there's no native functionality in GIMP which can do this.  Perhaps not a good idea to use GIMP for work that needs this kind of thing anyway. If you find yourself having to deal with a lot of text, like in a page layout, then maybe have a look at using Inkscape (which is also free and open source). It's easy to select multiple text boxes and change the font all in one go.

Answer (score -2):

You can Select All in All Layers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and use the Text and Font dialog to set the font.

It should work. Note that this applies only on **unlocked layers**.

Comment: Is this answer for Gimp? You cannot select more than one layer in Gimp... (And Ctrl-Alt-A isn't assigned to anything in my version).